# trying to count number of negative numbers in a list, python

Tags: python, list, math

Im trying to count the number of negative numbers in a 2d list, but my code keeps returning the wrong number. 
Here is the list:

```
[[4,3,2,-1],[3,2,1,-1],[1,1,-1,-2],[-1,-1,-2,-3]]
```

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def countNegatives(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        i = 0
        for x in grid:
            for x2 in x:
                if x2 < 0:
                    i =+1 
        return i
```

My code keeps returning 1, even though the correct answer is 8. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

```
i =+1
```

is quite a different statement to

```
i += 1
```

The former quite literally asks to set `i` equal to `+1` (`i = (+1)`) while the latter increments `i`

Answer (score 2):

I think you made a typo.

Change:

```
i =+1
```

To:

```
i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per-se, because I'm completely ignoring your code snippet, for two reasons:

1. People (e.g. @donkopotamus) have already answered by pointing out and explaining your code-typo.
2. I find your approach to be overkill (A whole class and dedicated method for a simple one-liner)

For future reference, here's a simple `numpy` approach:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[4,3,2,-1],[3,2,1,-1],[1,1,-1,-2],[-1,-1,-2,-3]]
print(np.sum(np.array(a) < 0))
```

or for a numpy-less solution:

```
print(sum([x < 0 for y in a for x in y]))
```

---

P.S: I'm using the "answer" format instead of just "commenting" due to the comment-section limitations and for clarity to future solution seekers.

Comment: The approach is fine. It's actually more efficient than the ones you've posted

Comment: Also a valid answer but for the context of the question I had no access to external libraries. The other answer without numpy would definitely work however.

Comment: Downvoted as you’re not answering the legitimate problem the questioner **actually** faced, leaving them free to make it again in the future in a different context.

Comment: @donkopotamus That's silly, because that's already been answered and accepted. I'm just adding useful info for the questioner's general benefit as well as future post readers...

Comment: @shlomif Then that’s a comment, not an answer

Comment: @donkopotamus too long for a comment. I'll edit the pseudo-answer to make my purpose more explicit